# Etiquette in Dealing with PhD offer

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, etiquette, united-kingdom

I've got an offer from a reputable University in the UK for a PhD in the Humanities. I've previously been in contact with the potential Supervisor. He very kindly invited me to apply but did not reply to the email after confirming I had actually applied. I did send him a follow-up asking for feedback following a notification regarding funding and got an offer a few hours later.
Is it okay for me to send a thank you or contact him before I decide to accept or reject the offer. (I've got a couple of other applications still ongoing at equally good Universities etc.)
Or is it expected that I should make up my mind first?
Thank you.

Comment: @astronat Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The best thing to do is send a short email thanking him for the offer and for his support of your application. Explain that you are waiting to hear back from a couple of other universities before making your decision. This is a perfectly reasonable thing to do, and no one would expect you to make a decision immediately.

Congratulations on the offer!

Comment: +1 I'll add: Waiting too long might lead to your offer going elsewhere.

Comment: @user2768 Thank you. 
I had a fruitful conversation today with the said my proposed supervisor!